# From CompModule to Alloy

Tags: alloy

Using the Alloy API, it is possible to get from an alloy file a CompModule that contains all the things you need in order to play around with that given alloy module.

This is easily achieved using : CompUtil.parseEverything_fromFile(...)

My question now is the following. Is there a way to go from a CompModule to alloy language ?
Or to go from a list of sigs, and facts to alloy model. ( I guess I could do it brute force, but I'd rather like to know if there's an utility existing.)

Thanks for your support !

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is already some kind of a visitor (or something) that takes a `CompModule` and produces a textual Alloy file.  Implementing such a printer should be pretty straightforward, but also time consuming.

Comment: That's what I feared.

I think it would be nice to have such a functionality. I'll find a workaround. 

Cheers !

Cheers

Comment: I agree.  If you end up writing a nice implementation and want to share it with us, I'll include it in the main Alloy distro.